# Visual Studio 2015: Auto-formatting code adds spaces instead of tabs

Tags: visual-studio-2015, indentation, spaces

My project uses tabs for indentation, but suppose I hit the enter/return button right where the cursor is shown, while writing a C# method in Visual Studio 2015 ..

[image]

Notice all the inserted spaces?

Basically, even though I have all Indentation settings set to "Keep tabs", the auto-inserted line breaks and indentations have spaces in them.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: My coworkers and I have seen our indentation settings revert to default a number of times without explanation. It's annoying. A [cursory search of The Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=visual+studio+indentiation+settings+revert&oq=visual+studio+indentiation+settings+revert&aqs=chrome..69i57.6316j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) reveals there may be a true bug.